# How to root Samsun Galaxy Tab S running Android 5.0.2?

Tags: root-access

I've been trying to root my Tab S (Model SM-T700).

I haven't gotten very far before encountering [this issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115972/issues-rooting-a-samsung-galaxy-tab-s).

What I have done is gotten the Google USB Driver installed -- meaning I can use adb.

If you didn't follow that link, basically my issue is that I can't `adb root`, since my tablet is in secure mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Okay, I rooted it.

I don't remember the precise process, but there are two important things I used:

- [Odin](http://odindownload.com/), the external rooting tool
- The knowledge that the "code name" for the SM-T700 is **klimtwifi**. Look that up instead of Samsung SM-T700 and you'll get a lot more stuff.